# About rules in prolog . .

Tags: prolog

In my program I have some rules like:

```
tellme(X) :- knows(X).
tellme(friends1(X)) :-  tellme(X).
tellme(friends2(X)) :-  tellme(X).
tellme(friends3(X)) :-  tellme(X).
.
.
.
tellme(friends25(X)) :- tellme(X).
```

Now this friends1, friends2, friends3 ..... are dependent on N which is a variable. Here, for example value of my N is 25. So is this possible to write a rule to generate these rules till N or do I have to manually write these rules for N times. Any suggestions or solutions are welcomed. Thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate any sort and amount of code in most modern Prolog environment using [term expansion](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=term_expansion/2), with some help from the [universal operator](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28=..%29/2).  The following example works for SWI:

```
term_expansion(gen_tellme(N), Terms) :-
    findall((tellme(F) :- tellme(X)),
            (between(1, N, I), atom_concat(friend, I, Fi), F =.. [Fi, X]),
            Terms).

gen_tellme(25). % generates 25 copies of the tellme clause.
```

That said, embedding information into the predicate name, i.e., the friend number, is generally not a good design.  Why not rewrite the code using `friend(N, X)`, where `N` is the number?

Comment: But it is giving me this error : ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: gen_tellme/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)

Comment: @anilonwebs: You need to consult both predicates together in the same file.  The first define a term expansion rule and the second uses it.  "gen_tellme()" is expanded, it does not become a real predicate.  Don't try this from the prompt.  Put it in a file.

Comment: See first thing that the base case is missing i.e. the first rule in my question part. So I add that in a file. `tellme(X) :- knows(X).` , `knows(anil).` with your define rule. But when I make a query for `tellme(friends1(anil))` it gives me false result. I have wrote all code in a single file.

Comment: @anilowebs: It's a type: I wrote "friend" instead of "friends".

Answer (score 1):

You may have some success with a binary functor `friends(N,X)` instead of one functor per `N`. You may want to change `tellme` and `knows` to take two arguments as well. (`knows(X)` has no immediate meaning to me, so I don't entirely get what you're after.)

If, for some reason, that's not what you want, you can make a new functor with something like (**untested**)

```
friends_functor(N, Functor) :-
    number(N),
    atom_concat(friend, N, Functor).
```

Then use `asserta` or `assertz`. I really don't see why you'd want to do this, though.